# Node JS npm not working properly

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

After uninstall and reinstalling node js from official site. npm not working as previous. version is showing there but not able to install any module and something error is showing there, see in attached file.
[image]

error when node installing.

[image]

After npm i lodash
But see I was talking about that error.
 "**'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules
\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external com
mand,**"

[image]

Comment: it's working, see `3.10.10` - version. try to do `npm i lodash` check if it will work

Comment: Update question..

Comment: So it works. It has installed it `-- lodash@4.17.4` check it: `dir node_modules`

Comment: people had same issue: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/11542  problem was with `PATH` variable, seems like old `PATH` refers to somewhere that nodejs does not exist.